# How to parse a youtubeURL to load video from parse.com when button is clicked using swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, video, parse-platform

Im trying to find the best way to load a video from my parse database In my swift project. I have a column called ProductVideo in the data base that I have the url of the video in. My project has a list of products in a tableview and when one of those cells is pushed it bring you to a new view controller that shows info about the project and there is a button called video there that I want to load the video when clicked. This is the code I have for unwrapping the object and showing the info. Some help with this would be much appreciated!

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var videoStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productVideo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var productCategory: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProductImage: PFImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productDescription: UITextView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Unwrap the current object object
    if let object = currentObject {
        productName.text = object["ProductName"] as? String
        productDescription.text = object["ProductDescription"] as! String
        productCategory.text = object["ProductCategory"] as? String
        videoStatus.text = object["VideoStatus"] as? String



        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        ProductImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
        if let thumbnail = object["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
            ProductImage.file = thumbnail
            ProductImage.loadInBackground()


            if self.videoStatus.text == "None"
            {
                self.productVideo.hidden = true
                self.videoView.hidden = true
            }


    }



    }





}
```

vvvThis is in the Tableview controller..^^^^the code above is from the productViewController

```
//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let ProductName = object?["ProductName"] as? String {
        cell.ProductName.text = ProductName
    }


    // Display product image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.ProductImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
    if let thumbnail = object?["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
        cell.ProductImage.file = thumbnail
        cell.ProductImage.loadInBackground()
    }



    return cell
}
```

Added this to the viewcontroller

```
@IBAction func productVideo2(sender: AnyObject) {


    let videoWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))

    let url = object["ProductVideo"] as! String // GET THIS FROM YOUR PARSE OBJECT

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    videoWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(videoWebView)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it would be done like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


// Unwrap the current object object
if let object = currentObject {
    productName.text = object["ProductName"] as? String
    productDescription.text = object["ProductDescription"] as! String
    productCategory.text = object["ProductCategory"] as? String
    videoStatus.text = object["VideoStatus"] as? String



    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    ProductImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
    if let thumbnail = object["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
        ProductImage.file = thumbnail
        ProductImage.loadInBackground()


        if self.videoStatus.text == "None"
        {
            self.productVideo.hidden = true
            self.videoView.hidden = true
        } else {


        let videoWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))

    let url = object["ProductVideo"] as! String // GET THIS FROM YOUR PARSE OBJECT

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    videoWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(videoWebView)

    }


}



}





}
```

**Update**

To use this as you intend you'll need to create a custom UIButton subclass with a property to hold the video Url that's present in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

**Storyboard**

Notice the custom UITableViewCell  and custom UIButton class assignments in the class inspector on the right.

[image]
[image]

**UIButton Subclass Example**

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomButton: UIButton {

    var videoUrl = ""

}
```

**UITableViewCell Subclass Example**

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellBttn: MyCustomButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

**View Controller Example**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//MARK: - ivars
var myData = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"] // Really just where your video URL is in your code

//MARK: - Overrides
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//MARK: - UITableViewMethods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

    cell.cellBttn.videoUrl = myData[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellBttn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellBttnTouched:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell

}

//MARK: - Actions
func cellBttnTouched(sender: MyCustomButton) {

    // Spawn your UIWebView here, you can get current video URL from the sender

    let thisCellsVideoUrl = sender.videoUrl
    println(thisCellsVideoUrl)


}

}
```

This example products this output when the button is tapped:
[image]

Comment: Yea i had something like this at first but the only problem is that I can't seem to get it to work to load the URL I have in parse. Even if it brings up the youtube app is fine too. I'm just completely stumped on this.

Comment: Updated my answer, assuming object has the ProductVideo column

Comment: Dude so close man! only thing is that when i clock on the cell for the table view it brings up the video automatically. How can it be set to load the video if the button productVideo is pushed?

Comment: then just move the creation of the UIWebView to your button action

Comment: I'm sorry i dont mean to be a pain but could you possibly update your answer to show me what you mean? Im getting an error with what I'm thinking you mean. I really appreciate this

Comment: I need to see the code for your UIButton and cellForRowAtIndexPath to accurately answer that, please update your question.

Comment: just updated but I dont have an action for the button I had it set as an outlet. should it be a button?

Comment: You will need to remove whatever is trigger the UIWebView to load from didSelectRowAtIndexPath then you will need to address the UIButton property inside of your cellForRowAtIndexPath and add a target action to it. You should load the UIWebView inside the target action.

Comment: when I put it in the action for the button its giving me an error because it can't connect the object to the product. Where it says let url = object it has an error at object saying "Use of unresolved identifier object". Any Idea on how to link it back to the object?

Comment: Create a custom subclass of the UIButton and add a property to hold the object

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your answer to show me man? I'm not totally sure what you mean

Comment: sure I will post a generic example because I don't know the details of your UITableViewCell in a few minutes

Comment: the button isn't in the cell though. its on the next view which is a view controller. with just a button at the bottom of the screen that says video. I wish i could show you a picture.

Comment: I've miss understood then, just add the code that plays the video to the button

Comment: so add                                                                                                               let videoWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))

    let url = object["ProductVideo"] as! String // GET THIS FROM YOUR PARSE OBJECT

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    videoWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(videoWebView)                                                                 ?

Comment: Or is their different code I have add for ti to work?

Comment: Yeah try that, you should try stuff first to see how it works. You'll need to make sure your object is accessible within your button's method.

Comment: just added an edit to what I added to my view controller but this is where I'm getting the error where it says object and the error states "Use of unresolved identifier object"

Comment: That is a different issue, it's because the scope of the object isn't accessible. I think you need to start with a new question to solve that issue. It's important to have clear and concise questions and answers on Stack Overflow so other people who come here can get the right information quickly, check out this meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-end-with-a-new-error